# Opening Files in Python with rb

Tags: python, windows, file

My question is why aren't all text files opened with the option 'rb' instead of just 'r' in python 2.7.X.

From the documentation:

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files.

it doesn't seem to state any drawbacks/consequences of applying 'rb' to when reading text files, only to be careful when reading data files containing binary data whilst not in binary mode.

I had a file containing the 'sub' character which would disrupt my program when trying to read lines after the 'sub' character. Would there be any problem if I changed my code to read all files with the 'rb' option to avoid any similar future problems? Also note that I am using a windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: because not all files need to be read (or written) in binary

Comment: If 'rb' is able to handle all file formats, what is the drawback of applying it when reading all files? Are there any consequences to opening all files in binary mode?

Comment: For reading a file in Python 2, you can use `'rU'` mode to enable universal newline translation (e.g. `'\r\n'` => `'\n'`). This actually opens the underlying `FILE` stream in binary mode. Notably, unlike the text mode provided by the Windows CRT, universal newlines doesn't handle Ctrl+Z (`'\x1a'`) as an end-of-file (EOF) marker.